# How do I use jGrasp's libraries?

Tags: import, jgrasp

I have a folder full of classes from a class I took. With a fresh install of jGrasp old projects that used to run fine are now full of "symbol not found" errors.

I still have the libraries, but I don't know how to import them. The way our class was set up, you didn't need import statements for anything that was in the library.

```
/* Turtle Drawing Program Lab 6, Part B */
/* Started by Celine Latulipe , modified by Bruce Long*/

public class Lab6PartB {
  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
    /* Create the world */
    World w = new World();

    /* Create the turtle, call him Tom */
    Turtle tom = new Turtle(w);

    /* test the getDistance2() method */
    int dist = tom.getDistance2();
    System.out.println("This should print out the value 400. Value is: " + dist);

    tom.moveTo(500, 400);
    dist = tom.getDistance2();
    System.out.println("This should print out the value 640. Value is: " + dist);

    // TODO: Add a third test case that you make up

  }
}
```

Error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Lab6PartB
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ModelDisplay
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ModelDisplay
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the directory containing the class files to the classpath, either at the OS level, or using "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" in jGRASP.

Also, you could copy all the class files/directories to the folder containing your new project classes.